# If the value of a determinant($n \times n $) is not equal to $0$, than the determinant has at least $n$ elements which are not equal to zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I assume that this is true, because at least in the diagonal has to be every element not equal to $0$, because the value of a determinant is equal to the multiplication of the diagonal elements. 
And in the diagonal has to be $n$ non zero elements.

Comment: what do you mean by the determinant has at least $n$ elements? shouldn't determinant be a number?

Comment: What about $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$? *All* entries of the diagonal are $0$, but the determinant isn't.

Comment: ^Exactly what I was coming here to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there has to be a permutation $\pi$ of $(1,\ldots, n)$ such that 
(if $A$ is the matrix) $A_{i,\pi(i)} \ne 0$ for all $i=1\ldots n$.  This follows 
from the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants).

Answer (score 4):

It's true, but not really for the reason you give, since a matrix
may have all its diagonal elements zero, but yet have a nonzero determinant.

But a matrix with fewer than $n$ nonzero elements has a row
consisting entirely of zeroes....